# AUROC or AUPRC?

Tags: classification, model-evaluation, unbalanced-classes, roc

I have a highly imbalanced dataset and want to evaluate the performance of a score. Is it better to balance the data and calculate the area under the receiver operating characteristic or to use the imbalanced data and calculate a area under the precision recall curve?

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/90779/area-under-the-roc-curve-or-area-under-the-pr-curve-for-imbalanced-data